# Update spring-security.xml to Spring 4.0.x

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a situation with a spring-security.xml file to update to spring-security 4.0. this is my xml file.

```
<!-- spring-security 3.2 -->
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2" 
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd">

<!-- Just for testing... -->
<!-- <http pattern="/oauth/cache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />
<http pattern="/oauth/uncache_approvals" security="none" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" />

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block so we can deal with authorization and error handling 
    separately. This isn't mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour.
<http pattern="/test/*" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/test/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http> -->

<beans:bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="test" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
    <beans:property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<beans:bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans:beans">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Used for the persistenceof tokens (currently an in memory implementation) -->
<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />


<!-- Used to create token and and every thing about them except for their persistence that is reposibility of TokenStore (Given here is a           default implementation) -->
<beans:bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <beans:property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <beans:property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userApprovalHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <beans:property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- authorization-server aka AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface that defines everything necessary for token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
<!-- ClientsDeailsService: Entry Point to clients database (given is in memory implementation) -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
<!-- client -->
<oauth:client client-id="the_client" authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

<oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client-with-secret" authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="somesecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Eclipse generates me this compiler error:

```
You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema or spring-security-3.2.xsd schema with Spring Security 4.0. Please update your schema declarations to the 4.0 schema.
```

and brand me the following lines

```
....
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
....
<beans:bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />
```

....

I'm basing this documentation

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html
    ....

Answer (score 7):

Simply remove the version number from the `xsi:schemaLocation`

> http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd

will pick up the appropriate version if there is only one spring-security-context.jar on the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

try to modify the `xsi:schemaLocation` in the `beans:beans` tag
and use *spring-security-4.0.xsd*

> xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/**spring-security-3.2.xsd**"